# Julia JuMP Cbc v 0.7.0. strange build date (Jan 1 1970) in a docker linux container

Tags: julia, julia-jump, coin-or-cbc

I've a linux docker container Ubuntu 16.04 with Julia 1.3.1 and JuMP 0.20.0. Recently I've updated Cbc package from 0.6.6 to the latest release 0.7.0. When printing log of the solver (log level set to 1), this is what I get:

Welcome to CBC MILP solver

Version: 2.10.3

Build date: Jan 1 1970

Is it only a question of parsing the date in the log? How can I check the real build date used?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is. I can't reproduce. I wouldn't worry about the compile date, 2.10.3 is the correct version.

```
julia> using Cbc, JuMP; model = Model(Cbc.Optimizer)
[ Info: Precompiling Cbc [9961bab8-2fa3-5c5a-9d89-47fab24efd76]
[ Info: Precompiling JuMP [4076af6c-e467-56ae-b986-b466b2749572]
A JuMP Model
Feasibility problem with:
Variables: 0
Model mode: AUTOMATIC
CachingOptimizer state: EMPTY_OPTIMIZER
Solver name: COIN Branch-and-Cut (Cbc)

julia> optimize!(model)
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: May 23 2020 

command line - Cbc_C_Interface -solve -quit (default strategy 1)
** Current model not valid
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.01


(cbc) pkg> st Cbc
Status `/private/tmp/cbc/Project.toml`
  [9961bab8] Cbc v0.7.0
```